# How can I determine the brightness of my materials so that it will work for most people?

Tags: shaders, color, color-management

I am working on a procedural road system that will also be used by other people.

Currently, I am searching for a method to ensure that the materials I create, such as asphalt and concrete, possess the appropriate default brightness. This way, they can seamlessly integrate with other assets like buildings and trees without encountering any issues.

When I utilize the default HDRI environments provided within Blender for rendering the viewport, I notice significant variations in brightness among them, despite setting the strength to 1 each time.

I created a color checker using 11 standard Principled BSDF shaders in the images below. The only modification I made was adjusting the color values.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In reality, most people's screens are not calibrated, and there are numerous external factors that can affect the viewing experience. However, I am still pondering the following:

Is it possible for me to create **a standard light setup or scene that serves as a baseline** for setting up all my materials with the appropriate brightness? Additionally, what steps should I take regarding the color management options?

Comment: *"In reality, most people's screens are not calibrated"* - I don't see how it's relevant to your problem. Let's present some extreme case, someone's monitor is wrongly calibrated so that he doesn't recognize colors brighter than 50% LED power. Half of colors are too bright. Why would you want to create an add-on to display properly for that user? Not only it is not your responsibility to deal with display problems of your user, what if the user intentionally has set up a screen this way?

Comment: Moreover, it's extremely niche to use Blender as the "end-user-tool", as in, I don't see people using Blender as a powerpoint, or a game engine (that is, the game runs Blender and Python scripts are responsible for the game logic), though if you target Blender Game Engine, it's a good idea to tag it in your question. Of course if your target audience are people using Blender as this "end-user-tool", I'm not saying it's wrong, but mentioning it explicitly (and maybe explaining in more detail) would clarify the question a lot.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I agree with you that the monitor calibration is not significant in relation to the question. The purpose of what I'm creating in Blender is not to develop a game. Instead, it is primarily intended for rendering illustrations of cityscapes in Blender. My concern lies in the scenario where I import assets that were made by other individuals at a later stage. If, for instance, my road system appears significantly darker compared to the imported assets, it would require me to adjust the brightness of the materials to achieve a cohesive look.

Comment: This adjustment process could potentially be time-consuming and labor-intensive, especially if it needs to be done repeatedly.
Therefore, I am searching for a method to give my materials a brightness that will work for most situations. It doesn't have to be precisely accurate or perfect.

Comment: If the colors of your assets is the same as the colors of other assets, everything will be fine, because you will render both in the same light and under same color management. If the colors are different, then they should be different, because color is just albedo property of a material meaning how much light it absorbs. For photorealistic workflow, you research what the albedo should be for a material. For NPR you need to standardize colors, or allow your setups, e.g. materials, geonode trees to have easily changeable colors. There is no standard color for anything in NPR.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady After giving it some thought, what you're saying actually makes a lot of sense! :-) It seems like placing it next to other assets is indeed the best approach. Thanks once again, Markus!